# Deserilize json string having prefix of node

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How can i deserialized json string having node with prefix like "ns:" in the start of node

```
{ "DetailsResults": {"ns:Address": "480  Street", "ns:City": "San Francisco", "ns:ErrorID": "0" }}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

For example apply Regex to remove the prefix and than deserialize

Comment: Use the Newtonsoft.Json library in particular the JObject.Parse(string str) method.